# Trying to use the "Use Specific Printer" option in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to set a report to use a specific printer. I go into design mode, 
click on the page setup ribbon, click the page setup bottun, go into the page 
tabt, click the option to choose a specific printer, and then click the 
printer button to choose the printer I want to use. 
I save the steps and exit out of the report, but it still goes back and 
prints from the default printer. Why? I had no problems with this feature in 
2003, why am I having problems in 2007. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated, 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printer settings are saved with the objects themselves. That is, if you print a report and choose a different printer, you have to change the printer and then save the report for that setting to be retained the next time you open the printer.

This can also be done programmatically, but that's probably more than what you need here.

Answer (score 0):

it's a known Access 2007 Bug!
See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/950488